# How to make submit button in line with the search fields?

Tags: forms, html

I have a search field and I want my search button image to be in line with the search fields but it isn't. I have used div tags to try and move it but it always moves the search fields not just the button!

HELP!

```
<form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" size="35" value="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager"  
    style="background-color:white; border: 
    solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 30px; font-size:18px; 
    vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager'){this.value = '';this.style.color='#000'}" />
  <input type="text" name="searchterm" size="35" value="Location e.g. Manchester"   
    style="background-color:white; border: 
    solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 30px; font-size:18px; 
    vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'Location e.g. Manchester'){this.value = '';this.style.color='#000'}" />
  <input type="image" src="but.tiff" alt="Submit" height="30" width="60">
</form>
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: I can't read your code. Try using a stylesheet for your CSS...

Comment: What do you mean by "inline." As it is written, the two input boxes and the button are all on one line.

Comment: Yes please so its all level on the same line

Comment: What about use the <table> tags? It helps aligning stuff.

Comment: @Andrey <table> should never be used to layout stuff.  tables are use to represent data.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and put all the styling in a separate css file.  Then import this one into your HTML.  This Html is unreadable.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's inline to me.  You possibly have a problem because your using a tiff file for that button.  I'd convert that to a JPG.

[image]

If yours doesn't look like this you possibly have some other css in your project that is breaking your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use floats - eg: input { float: left } on each element, that should do the trick.

Comment: also ensure you have enough space for each element to sit side by side, try defining a width for elements to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

http://jsfiddle.net/TMy6p/

I have moved your styling into an external stylesheet to tidy it up a bit and help you to avoid repeating the same style tags on elements.

basically you just need to float elements and give them widths.